# Connecting to DB2z with JupyterLab SQL Magic throw Programming error: "CURRENT" is not valid

Tags: python, db2, jupyter

I try to set up a Jupyter Notebook to use SQL Magic (% and %% notation) to access an IBM DB2z database.

I followed this tutorial installing DB2 SQLAlchemy Drivers:
https://blog.4loeser.net/2016/11/sql-magic-in-notebooks-in-ibm-data.html

Now my code in Jupyter Lab looks like this:

```
!pip install --user ipython-sql 
!pip install --user ibm_db
!pip install --user ibm_db_sa

import getpass
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_sa
import sqlalchemy

user = input("User: ")
passw = getpass.getpass("Passwort: ")

# loads the SQL magic extensions
%load_ext sql
%sql db2+ibm_db://$user:$passw@xxx.xxx.xx:55555/XXX
```

But leads to the following error:

```
(ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: 
SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0206N  "CURRENT" is 
not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703 SQLCODE=-206 
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
           postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
           or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

I can exclude errors in username password or driver as an implementation using pandas works:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

engine = create_engine("db2+ibm_db://"+user+":"+passw+"@xxx.xxx.xx:55555/XXX")
#Read Data query into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_sql("""select * from XXX.XXXXX limit 1""", engine)
df.head()
```

There seems to be a Problem with the keyword CURRENT but I can not figure out what the difference between pandas and SQL Magic is in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a known issue in the ibm_db_sa module.
See this [issue](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa/issues/51) which at present time, seems to be awaiting a fix.
It may be wise to chase this via github instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks I'll look there

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using ibm_db alongside ibm_db_dbi wrapper.   Please see my db2 post for better explanation